# What's happening to my rosemary plant -is it dying?

Tags: water, rosemary

[image]

I don't know how it happened i water as i was told and it is still like this but still smell good don't know if this happens to others any solutions.

Is there any hope for my rosemary plant?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you your Rosemary is completely dead; it doesn't look like a new plant, maybe you've had it some time, but quite why its died is hard to diagnose without more information, such as how long its been in that pot, how often and how much you watered it, local climate, etc.

Comment: I water it once a week but sometimes twice a week. Its been in pot for like 2/3months. It leaves started falling 3 week ago so i shifted pot with some soil and old fertilizer. It still have fragrance tho. Climate here is usually 23° - 30° usually

Comment: Most likely cause is drought... in hot sun. pot plants (especially in smaller pots) need watering probably once a day, with enough water to run out the bottom of the pot through the drainage holes. Rosemary wood remains fragrant even though its dead, it does not indicate life.

Comment: Is there any hope for it? Like is it still possible that i can revive it

Comment: No.... its dead, get rid of it and get a new one.

Comment: Thankful for your response.